# Can't import an svg using React + Typescript + Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to include an SVG in a page while using React + Typescript + Vite. I've been looking at blogs like https://dev.to/cassidoo/importing-svg-files-as-react-components-with-vite-l3n and they all say the same thing, use vite-plugin-svgr, but it isn't working for me.

Here is my `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(),svgr()],
  test: {
    testTimeout: 2000,
    hookTimeout: 2000,
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
  },
});
```

Here is the import statement of my component

```
import { ReactComponent as RedDie } from './images/red-die.svg';
```

Here is my directory structure

```
src/
    App.tsx
    images/
        red-die.svg
```

I'm getting the following error in VSCode.

```
Cannot find module 'assets/red-die.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

When I try to visit the page I get a 404 message that says

```
Cannot GET /
```

Note that I am building the front end and serving it staticly with node rather than using the vite dev server. See [Use vite and express at the same time by sharing cookies or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750246/use-vite-and-express-at-the-same-time-by-sharing-cookies-or-something)

Answer (score 1):

The api got changed
from [vite-plugin-svgr npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr)

SVG files can be imported as React components

```
import Logo from "./logo.svg?react";
```

notice the `?react`

If you are using TypeScript, there is also a declaration helper for better type inference:

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```